# How to populate Objects in a an existing file

Tags: python, file

My Question is How do i populate objects into some existing file. let say my file name is "abc.txt" . I mean fname, lname, age, gender should all get populated into the file

```
#!usr/bin/python

class People:

    def __init__(self, fname=None, lname=None, age=None, gender=None):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def display(self):
        print self.fname

    ppl1 = People('John','W','Cooper',23,'Male')
    ppl2 = People('Jack','A','Kalis',40,'Male')
    ppl1.display()
    ppl2.display()
```

Comment: Do you mean how do you write these People objects to a text file?

Comment: yes. and when written I will make a search if John string is present in fname or not. Similarly for lname, age etc...

Comment: Why do you want to save into some file? Do you want human-readable data file like csv?

Comment: no. i will jus write this object in a file and make a search in a file . see my above comment @EveryEvery

Comment: if you want search in a file, how about use sqlite library? Just add ing new people in a file is easy, however search/update/delete in file is not easy.

Comment: you may want to google for "database"...

Comment: My Question was How do i populate objects into the file that i have read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class People:

    def __init__(self, fname=None, lname=None, age=None, gender=None):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

def display(self):
    print self.fname

people = [People('John','W Cooper',23,'Male'),
           People('James','W Cooper',30,'Male'),
           People('Kate','W Cooper',20,'Female')]
f = open("abc.txt", "w")
for person in people:
    f.write( person.fname +","+ person.lname +","+ str(person.age) +","+ person.gender + '\n' )
    person.display()
f.close()
```

Comment: I want the objects to get written. Moreover i have so many objects.

Comment: How can I write two objects ?? please help

Comment: Have edited the script. Hope it works for you.

Comment: when i write people.display() at last line it shows error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'display'

Comment: people is now a list because it contains more than 1 person. You can write person.display() in side the loop. Have modified the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you do simply wish to write the attributes (comma separated) to a file, you can do:

```
ppl = People('John', 'Cooper', 23, 'Male')

f = open('abc.txt', 'w')
ppl_attrs = [ppl.fname, ppl.lname, str(ppl.age), ppl.gender]
f.write(','.join(ppl_attrs))
f.close()
```

Comment: The `csv` module is still highly recommended when you want to write csv files...

Comment: can i write the objects ??

Comment: Would you like to write the objects in binary form?  Sounded like you needed to grep through the file afterward?

Comment: Agreed, `csv` is a must in general.  I was just trying to give a short example and didn't want the csv code to take up half the answer.

Comment: No not in binary form. I just want the object should get into the text file and my requirement is whenever i would search a string like "John" it would search i firstname and display. Moreover i have more objects not jus only one

Answer (score 0):

As described in the python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) you just need to write to the end of a file (after checking if it first exists).

Answer (score 0):

```
ppl = People('John W','Cooper',23,'Male')

with open("abc.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(",".join((ppl.fname, ppl.lname, str(ppl.age), ppl.gender)))
```

Comment: do it write only the attributes ? like john W cooper 23 male would get into the file simply ?

Comment: This snippet writes: `John W,Cooper,23,Male` on file. I used comma because spaces can be misleading (e.g. 'John W')

Comment: Now suppose i want more than one object to get in the text file ? how that can be happened ?

Answer (score 0):

I you just want to save, file is ok. but db is better choice.
sqlite is very simple and good db and it is included in python.
how about use sqlite?

below is example code. (sorry. quick and dirty code)

```
#!usr/bin/python

import sqlite3

class People:

    def __init__(self, fname=None, lname=None, age=None, gender=None):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('people.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""create table if not exists
                     tbl_people(fname text, lname text,
                                age integer, gender text,
                                primary key (fname, lname) )""")
        c.execute("""insert or replace into tbl_people(fname, lname, age, gender)
                     values ('%s', '%s', %d, '%s')
                  """ % (self.fname, self.lname, self.age, self.gender) )
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


    def display(self):
        print self.fname

def search(fname, lname):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('people.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("select * from tbl_people where fname='%s' and lname='%s'"%(fname,lname))
    ppl = c.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    if ppl is not None:
        return People(ppl[0], ppl[1], ppl[2], ppl[3])
    else:
        return None

ppl = People('John','Cooper',23,'Male')
ppl2 = People('Jane','Cooper',22,'Female')
ppl3 = search('John', 'Cooper')
ppl.display()
ppl3.display()
```

Comment: This looks scary. I am jus above newbie